jupyter отказывается импортировать pandas
столкнулся с очень подлой проблемой. установил пакет anaconda, jupyter, запустил блокнот, предварительно установив pandas. при попытке импорта выкидывает alert о срочной перезагрузке ядра, при этом pandas не импортируется. тогда я попробовал сделать так:
!pip install pandas
import pandas

и всё равно выдаёт тоже самое. подскажите, что делать?
p.s. не знаю, что ещё сказать, если надо, дам доп информацию
p.s.s. у меня arch

Так ядро то перегружали? А окружение то же выбрано, в которое pandas ставили?

да, пробовал ставить pandas через дефолтный канал, пробовал через conda-forge, pip3. ничего не помогло

Попробуй через командную строку
conda activate <твоё conda окружение>
conda install pandas

После этого перезагрузи jupyter
